# Passing "state" to Task Parallel Library when wrapping APM style

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, azure-table-storage

I have the following extension method that I'd like to pass state to:

```
     // Overload 2
    public static Task<TableQuerySegment<T>> ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<T> (this CloudTable tbl, TableQuery<T> query, TableContinuationToken continuationToken, CancellationToken token) where T : ITableEntity, new()
    {
        return tbl.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<T>(query, continuationToken, null, null, token);
    }

    // Overload 5
    public static Task<TableQuerySegment<TElement>> ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<TElement>(this CloudTable tbl, TableQuery<TElement> query, TableContinuationToken continuationToken, TableRequestOptions opt, OperationContext ctx, CancellationToken token) where TElement : ITableEntity, new()
    {
        ICancellableAsyncResult result = null;

        if (opt == null && ctx == null)
            result = tbl.BeginExecuteQuerySegmented<TElement>(query, continuationToken, null, tbl);
        else
            result = tbl.BeginExecuteQuerySegmented<TElement>(query, continuationToken, opt, ctx, null, tbl);

        var cancellationRegistration = token.Register(result.Cancel);

        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, iAsyncResult =>
        {
            CloudTable currentTable = iAsyncResult.AsyncState as CloudTable;

            cancellationRegistration.Dispose(); // todo: handle cleanup of this (deregistration)
            return currentTable.EndExecuteQuerySegmented<TElement>(result);
        });
    }

    // Overload 3
    public static Task<TableQuerySegment<R>> ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<T, R>(this CloudTable tbl, TableQuery<T> query, EntityResolver<R> resolver, TableContinuationToken continuationToken, CancellationToken token) where T : ITableEntity, new()
    {
        return tbl.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<T, R>(query, resolver, continuationToken, null, null, token);
    }

    // Overload 6
    public static Task<TableQuerySegment<R>> ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<TElement, R>(this CloudTable tbl, TableQuery<TElement> query, EntityResolver<R> resolver, TableContinuationToken continuationToken, TableRequestOptions opt, OperationContext ctx, CancellationToken token) where TElement : ITableEntity, new()
    {
        ICancellableAsyncResult result = null;

        if (opt == null && ctx == null)
            result = tbl.BeginExecuteQuerySegmented<TElement, R>(query, resolver, continuationToken, null, null);
        else
            result = tbl.BeginExecuteQuerySegmented<TElement, R>(query, resolver, continuationToken, opt, ctx, null, null);

        var cancellationRegistration = token.Register(result.Cancel);

        return Task.Factory.FromAsync(result, iAsyncResult =>
        {
            CloudTable currentTable = iAsyncResult.AsyncState as CloudTable;

            cancellationRegistration.Dispose(); // todo: handle cleanup of this (deregistration)
            return currentTable.EndExecuteQuerySegmented<R>(result);
        });
    }
```

so I can call the code like this

```
            // prepare the query
            trustsInBatchesOf100 = tableSymmetricKeys.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token, opt, ctx, cancelToken);

            // my state
            object mystate  = trustsInBatchesOf100.AsyncState;
```

I'm stuck trying to figure out how I should modify the extension methods to include a `stateObject`.  The difficulty is me locating the correct overload in [TaskFactory.FromAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync.aspx) and implementing it correctly in the Extension Methods.

**Question**

> How can I modify the extension methods above to correctly accept a state parameter?

**More source code**

```
    private CloudTableClient tableClient;
    private CloudStorageAccount account;
    private TableRequestOptions opt;

    List<Task<TableResult>> AllRunningTasks = null;

    public async Task GetTrustsAndValues(string thingToSearchFor,string trustStartingPoint, 
        int depth,
        TableQuery query,                             
         OperationContext ctx, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        TrustState asyncState = new TrustState() { ThingToSearchFor = thingToSearchFor, TimeStarted = DateTime.UtcNow };

        var ret = new TrustTree<string>(thingToSearchFor, "start", 10);


        CloudTableClient client = account.CreateCloudTableClient();
        CloudTable tableSymmetricKeys = client.GetTableReference("SymmetricKeys5"); 

       // List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

        TableContinuationToken token = new TableContinuationToken() { };
        Task<TableQuerySegment<DynamicTableEntity>> trustsInBatchesOf100 = null;

        while (true)
        {
            // prepare the query
            trustsInBatchesOf100 = tableSymmetricKeys.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, token, opt, ctx, cancelToken);

            object mystate  = trustsInBatchesOf100.AsyncState;

            // Run the method
            trustsInBatchesOf100.Wait();

            // Create tasks for each of the 100 domains found.
            IEnumerable<Task<TableResult>> getTrustDataQuery =
                          from domainData in trustsInBatchesOf100.Result select QueryPartnerForData(ref ret,domainData, thingToSearchFor, client, cancelToken);

            // Save the count of lookups as appropriate  
            asyncState.RunningDirectQueries = getTrustDataQuery.Count();

            // Run up to 100 lookups on those domains.
            var runningTasks = getTrustDataQuery.ToList();

            // Add running tasks to the full compilation of running tasks
            AllRunningTasks.AddRange(runningTasks );

            // Prepare for next iteration or quit
            if (token == null)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                token = trustsInBatchesOf100.Result.ContinuationToken;

                // todo: persist token  token.WriteXml()
            }
        }
    }



    private static Task<TableResult> QueryPartnerForData(ref  TrustTree<string> tree, DynamicTableEntity domainData, string thingToSearchFor, CloudTableClient client, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
        // Create the table client.
        CloudTable tableDirectQuery = client.GetTableReference(String.Format("{0}_FW", domainData.RowKey));

        // Retrieve the entity with partition key of "Smith" and row key of "Jeff"
        TableOperation tableOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve(domainData.RowKey, thingToSearchFor);

        // Retrieve entity asynchronously
        return tableDirectQuery.ExecuteAsync(tableOperation, cancelToken);
    }

    public async void SaveCompletedQueriesTo()
    {
        while (AllRunningTasks.Count > 0)
        {
            // Identify the first task that completes.
            Task<TableResult> firstFinishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(AllRunningTasks);

            // ***Remove the selected task from the list so that you don't
            // process it more than once.
            AllRunningTasks.Remove(firstFinishedTask);

            // Await the completed task.
            var taskOfTableResult = await firstFinishedTask;

            //todo: asyncState: need to know what the 
            // - target to save to is.
        }

        // TODO: if all tasks have completed then update 
    }
```

Comment: `Task.AsyncState` is usually not used. Could you explain why exactly do you need it? There's most likely a better way to do what you want that doesn't involve using `AsyncState` (or casting, which is necessary with `AsyncState`).

Comment: @svick I'm doing recursion with Tasks that branches down a "tree".  I'm thinking of using AsyncState to track where the process is (what level, and what branch) of the tree.  As you can see I'm using Azure Tables.  My goal is to have the same variable for each round of "continuationTokens", but slightly altered state for each recursion.  I'll post more source if you're interested...

Comment: I don't see the recursion in your code, or the need for `AsyncState`. Maybe you could simplify your code so that it contains only parts relevant to your question? Also, be careful about using `Count()` the way you do on `getTrustDataQuery`, because it means the whole collection will be iterated twice.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen the [Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Async](https://github.com/AArnott/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Async) project? (also [available on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Async)). It may provide some ideas, or already solved your problem. Otherwise, please consider contributing your changes to that project when you've got them right.

Comment: Not sure why there is a down vote on this answer, but I also have a git project for the same  ...https://github.com/makerofthings7/AzureStorageExtensions